# How to open a text file from matlab to view?

Tags: matlab, fopen

I am having a text file and I want to view it through Matlab command instead of opening it through the file manager.

I have tried the following:

```
fid= fopen('exp.txt','r');
```

But its not opening. Any anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: `fopen` just open the file and return a file identifier that you have to use to actually read the content of the file, take a look to `fread` [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html)

Comment: "its not opening" is not clear enough. Please state your question **in detail and clear**

Comment: I mean that I want to display the text file(rather than opening through the file manager each time-as the output is saved in the text file). Is there any command for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load the file into MATLAB-Editor use

```
uiopen('exp.txt',1)
```

Important is, that the file belongs to MATLAB-path. If it doesn't, you have to add it first!

Answer (score 0):

Use `load` function instead. Then you can display the file using `disp` or just don't write `;`.